# In magnet and conductor problem, what is the source of electric field?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction, relative-motion

I have difficulty understanding forces involved in moving magnet and conductor problem.

When a ring conductor is at rest and an ordinary bar magnet is moving, there's electric force. I have trouble understanding how the electric force arise here. Based on my understanding of Faraday's law, there should be induced current flowing in the ring conductor. So the electric force is responsible for creating current?

Here is what I mean by electric force creating current: Consider this example where the magnetic field out the page is moving to the left towards the stationary wire loop

[image]

Faraday's law tells me that the current should be flowing clockwise. I am not sure what are forces involved here. There is no magnetic force since the loop is stationary so there's electric force somewhere and I'm not sure where it came from and its direction. According to this equation $\nabla \times \vec{E} = -\frac{\partial \vec{B}}{\partial t}$, it looks like there is electric field flowing clockwise direction like the current. So the clockwise electric field which produces electric force is responsible for creating clockwise current?

Take a look at this image from [this Wikipedia article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_magnet_and_conductor_problem),

[image]

I understand where the magnet force is coming from in the magnet frame (one with blue coordinates). But in the conductor frame (one with primed red coordinates), I have trouble understanding where the electric force came from. I don't know the source of electric field and why it points downwards. Also, I'm not sure why the primed red coordinates is moving in +x direction (see the dotted arrow). It is supposed to move in -x direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> According to this equation $\nabla \times E = -\frac{\partial B}{\partial t}$, it looks like there is electric field flowing clockwise direction like the current. So the clockwise electric field which produces electric force is responsible for creating clockwise current?

Yes.

Comment: So how do you apply Faraday's law to explain the electric field in the second image?

Comment: @JimmyYang I don't understand your confusion, unfortunately. Isn't that the same situation as the first image?

Comment: There’s a bar conductor in the second image and I have no idea how and in what direction current flows in the bar.

Comment: Hmm, consider a situation different from the first image: wire loop is moving to the right to stationary magnetic field. I am told that magnetic force is responsible for creating current but it seems like I can similarly argue using Faraday’s law that electric force is also responsible for creating current? So when the loop moves towards magnetic field, both magnetic and electric force is responsible for creating current in the loop?

Comment: @JimmyYang I think I might be seeing what you're getting at. Take the first image. If the loop of wire is still and the region with the magnetic field is moving to the left, then the magnetic field at a fixed point is changing, which leads to an electric field, which drives current in the loop. If the loop of write is moving and the region with the magnetic field is not changing, then the moving charges in the wire are pushed by the magnetic field to create a current. (...)

Comment: (...) It may bother you that there are two physically different explanations for the same current, even though all we did was change from one inertial reference frame to another. Indeed, this also bothered Einstein, and this exact problem motivated him to develop special relativity. His paper is a classic and worth a read, the first paragraph is (I think) the exact issue you are getting at: https://einsteinpapers.press.princeton.edu/vol2-trans/154

Comment: Thanks, I am aware of this paper and I read most of it. The problem right now is that I don't understand why there's no electric force or electric field when the wire loop is moving toward the stationary magnetic field, only magnetic force exists.

Comment: @JimmyYang The time derivative of the magnetic field is zero in the case when the loop is moving toward the magnetic field. Then Maxwell's equation becomes $\nabla \times E = \partial B/\partial t = 0$, so there is no time-dependent magnetic field sourcing the electric field. The fact that $\partial B/\partial t = 0$ is maybe more obvious if you just take away the loop -- obviously the loop being present or not cannot affect the applied magnetic field.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, I think I got it now!